# Deterministic length of JS new Date().getTime() string in the modern era: Unix Epoch Time

Tags: javascript, date, unix-timestamp, epoch

```js
console.log(new Date().getTime());
```

I have a silly question: In the modern era, is the length of JS `new Date().getTime()` always **13**? Both JS and Java give time strings of this length.

My issue is that I have a random JS string created with

```
function generateUniqueID() {
    return new Date().getTime() + '' + Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(10,6));
}
```

This string concatenates a Time string with a random number. I need to compare 2 IDs to see which one is for an **earlier** Date. But the random part of this string isn't always a 6-digit number, so I can't truncate the trailing 6 digits and consider that the time string. To get the time string, I can consider the first 13 digits. That seems to be the Unix Epoch Time string in the modern era.

But is that reliable? When would `getTime()` start giving 14 digits?

Also, if I look up Unix Epoch Time on Wikipedia, I see a 10-digit number as the current Unix Time, not 13-digit: `1637093681`.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

**Updated**
I see the length changes at this point: `2281-11-20` and `2281-11-21`

```js
console.log(new Date('2286-11-20').getTime().toString().length);
console.log(new Date('2286-11-21').getTime().toString().length);
```

Comment: Why not `crypto.randomUUID()`? Or `String(new Date().getTime()).padStart(13, "0")`?

Comment: I am working with existing code, I can't change the way identifiers are created. I just need to compare the time portions.

Comment: It will become 14 digits in 265 years.

Comment: @geneb. see `new Date('2286-12-31').getTime().toString().length`

Comment: Yes, I see the change occurs between 2286-11-20 and 2286-11-21.

Comment: The first 13 digit time value is `1000000000000` which gives "2001-09-09T01:46:40.000Z". The last is `9999999999999` which gives "2286-11-20T17:46:39.999Z". So any ECMAScript Date in that roughly 286 year interval will have a 13 digit time value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamp is milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (the same as the Unix epoch). Subtract the current timestamp from `10000000000000` to get the number of milliseconds until it overflows to 14 digits, which is `8,362,906,319,000`. Then divide this by the number of milliseconds in a year, which is about `31,557,600,000`, to get the number of years until it reaches that value.

This is about 265 years.

Comment: Thanks. I see the change occurs between 2286-11-20 and 2286-11-21. I'll update the OP

Comment: Do you know why the Wikipedia article on Unix times gives a 10-digit number? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Unix timestamps are seconds, JavaScript uses milliseconds.

Comment: Simpler to do `new Date(1000000000000).getFullYear() - new Date(9999999999999).getFullYear()` which is 285 (close enough for the OP's purpose I think). :-)

Comment: @RobG That's true, but my answer explains where these numbers come from, so I thought it was more informative.